# Which architecture to use for multiple small specific servers and a centralized one?

Tags: database, rest, architecture, distributed-computing, distributed

First of all: I'm a newb. Its my first time working in a important project.

This is my plan:

[image]

**How it works now:**
The rasp has a state based on the others connected to the same computer. The computer has an algorithm to calculate these states.

The rasp also generate data every second, and send it directly to the server using http requests.

The server shows a page to the user based on rasp properties, where the user want to have access to the rasp state, memory load, camera stream and also send commands.

Every new Computer needs to be registered on the Server Computer, also every Computer and Rasp properties.

So if I add a new camera to the rasp, someone needs to update the Server database.

This approach is not very scalable. I'm targeting a very scalable solution.
**So, I'm considering:**

- Each computer has an individual database and an API answer http requests. This database hold rasp information, like the cameras, current state, etc...
- In this approach, it's better to the computer send the information or to the server asks for it?
- The server has access to the Computers databases via database synchronization (I need to do a better research about this). So, no to individual APIs, only individual databases synchronized with the server.
- Suggestions?

**OBS:** in the current state, all the rasps, computers and the server are inside a single VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you bothering with the intermediary computers/databases?  Have the Raspberry make HTTP request to central server to "register" itself, and have it send it's content periodically to that centralized server.

If there is too much load, split that centralized server into application/database tiers and load-balance the application tier.  If there is still too much load on the database, re-architect your database.

Having multiple sources of "truth" is one of the biggest downfalls of an application design.  Don't try and synchronize your way out of this, just create a single point of truth.  If you need to scale that centralized db higher, then look at solutions that are amenable to that, like NoSQL solutions instead of trying to distribute it out to the clients.

Comment: Both the Computer and the Server needs to have updated information about the rasps. The rasps are connected to the computer in a local network, while the Computer and the Server are distant and the connection is not good.

Comment: If I keep the source of "truth" on the Computer, the user experience will be pretty slow. If I keep the source of "truth" on the Server, the alogrithm will take to long to compute the rasps states.

Answer (score 0):

> In this approach, it's better to the computer send the information or to the server asks for it?

Let the server request the data when it needs it... and when it can! If the computers send data whenever they feel it, your server may have performance problems.

> The server has access to the Computers databases via database synchronization (I need to do a better research about this). So, no to individual APIs, only individual databases synchronized with the server.

Try to make the replication one-way only, so identify the tables used for the computers' data and do not write in them on the server.
Database replication may be a solution for information sharing, but it implies a heavy coupling of the systems because of the schema structure. Isolate the shared tables.

> Suggestions?

- Use a database that supports replication (mySql does, I think), don't write your own system
- Compute/aggregate/adapt the data on your computers to make the work of the server easier

> Every new Computer needs to be registered on the Server Computer

- Have a look at tools like Consul